Kotlin slow compilation
I have a kotlin project and when i do mvn compile the project takes 30s+ to build.
When using the -X flag it stops on this step for kapt and for the compiler for ~15s
What should I do to make this faster?
[DEBUG] Loading modules: [java.se, jdk.accessibility, jdk.attach, jdk.compiler, jdk.dynalink, jdk.httpserver, jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.jartool, jdk.javadoc, jdk.jconsole, jdk.jdi, jdk.jfr, jdk.jshell, jdk.jsobject, jdk.management, jdk.management.jfr, jdk.net, jdk.nio.mapmode, jdk.sctp, jdk.security.auth, jdk.security.jgss, jdk.unsupported, jdk.unsupported.desktop, jdk.xml.dom, java.base, java.compiler, java.datatransfer, java.desktop, java.xml, java.instrument, java.logging, java.management, java.management.rmi, java.rmi, java.naming, java.net.http, java.prefs, java.scripting, java.security.jgss, java.security.sasl, java.sql, java.transaction.xa, java.sql.rowset, java.xml.crypto, jdk.internal.jvmstat, jdk.management.agent, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.internal.ed, jdk.internal.le, jdk.internal.opt]


My guess is that you have a dependency that needs to be checked, perhaps because it is a "SNAPSHOT" version and this is what incurs the time penalty via an external slow or timing out resource server.
But without any source code it is anyone's guess what is not right.  So do this:

make a single mistake in any random file and see if the compilation terminates a lot earlier.
If this does reduce the time, move this mistake to different files to try to work out what class is now not being compiled which causes the delay
Remove dependencies - which again will cause failures, but may lead upi to which is the dependency causing the delay.
if you are no closer to working out the problem start removing classes  and dependencies such that the project still compiles but still takes "too" long
... eventually you will remove the "bad" class/dependency and compilation will happen in a reasonable time and you'll have found the problem.

